# Error al recorrer un for para una insercion

Tags: php, mysql

[[image: Datos de la tabla cuotas]

Presento un problema al insertar esos datos, debo insertar en la tabla costos_cuotas la cantidad de montos que yo le diga, por ejemplo cantidad de cuotas: 9, bueno segun ese numero que le pase debe insertar esa cantidad de veces el dato en la tabla costo_cuotas, como se ve en la imagen, ademas cada 3 campos debo hacer un aumento del 20% del monto anterior. El problema radica en que como ven el primer aumento comienza en el campo costo3 y deberia empezar en costo4, ya luego si lo hace cada 3 campos, pero al empezar lo hace en el campo3, lo unico que he pensado es como si hubiese un campo costo0, o que tenga algun error en como planteo el for. Le he dado vueltas pero no he podido encontrarle solucion, aca esta la funcion que me hace la insercion y los aumentos][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKxVC.png)

```
function cuotas($cantidad,$monto)
{
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'pruebas');

$query = "INSERT INTO cuotas (cantidad) VALUES('$cantidad')";
$sql = $mysqli->query($query);

$val = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

$campos = "";
$valores = "";
$porcentaje = 0.2;
$aumenta = 3;

for($i = 1; $i <= $cantidad; $i++){
  if(($i>=1) && ($i % $aumenta)==0):
    $monto = $monto*(1+$porcentaje);
  endif;
  $campos .= 'costo' . $i . ' , ';
  $valores .= '' . $monto . ' , ';

}

if($campos != ''):
  $campos = substr($campos, 0, -2);
  $valores = substr($valores, 0, -2);
endif;

$query2 = "INSERT INTO 
costo_cuotas(id_cantidad,$campos)VALUES($val,$valores)";
$sql2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fíjate en la parte del ciclo **FOR**

> hazlo empezar desde 0

Ejecutas y funciona tal como lo necesitas, te detallo el código que corri en consola comentando algunas lineas.

```
function cuotas($cantidad,$monto)
{

  $query = "INSERT INTO cuotas (cantidad) VALUES('$cantidad')";
  // $sql = $mysqli->query($query);
  // $val = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

  $campos = "";
  $valores = "";
  $porcentaje = 0.2;
  $aumenta = 3;

  for($i = 0; $i < $cantidad; $i++){
    if(($i>=1) && ($i % $aumenta)==0):
      $monto = $monto*(1+$porcentaje);
    endif;

    $datoTemporal = $i + 1;
    $campos .= 'costo' . $datoTemporal . ' , ';

    $valores .= '' . $monto . ' , ';

  }

  if($campos != ''):
    $campos = substr($campos, 0, -2);
    $valores = substr($valores, 0, -2);
  endif;

  echo $query2 = "INSERT INTO costo_cuotas(id_cantidad,$campos) VALUES ('3',$valores)";
  //$sql2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
}

cuotas('9','20000');
```

Comment: Saludos Alan, he hecho eso pero mira lo que me dice: Unknown column 'costo0' in 'field list'  dice que la columna costo0 no existe. es porque en mi tabla no esta ese campo, y intente colocando ese campo en la tabla, pero entonces me agrega un dato de mas. le digo que me inserte 9 y me va a insertar 10 veces porque lo inicio en 0. Que solucion podria tomar?

Comment: Ah solucionado Alan, hice lo que me dijiste, y agregue el campo costo0 a la tabla, y en el for le puse $i < $cantidad, anterior estaba $i <= $cantidad. Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Dentro del FOR, despues del endif, prueba con lo siguiente:
$datoTemporal = $i + 1;
$campos .= 'costo' . $datoTemporal . ' , ';

Comment: Solucionado Alan. Muchas Gracias